# Member of a group cannot access a WS2008 network share

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, user-permissions, shared-storage, permissions

A Windows 8.1 user cannot access one specfic network share on a windows 2008 R2 server.

> Windows cannot access \\COMPUTERNAME\Users You do not have permission
>   to access \\COMPUTERNAME\Users. Contact your network administrator to
>   request access.

- The shared folder is configured to be accessible to a group, with full control
- The shared folder has filesystem security set to full control to the same group
- Other users in the same group can access the shared folder (they are not part of Administrators and Domain Admins)
- The blocked user can access other shares on the server
- The blocked user is also part of Administrators and Domain Admins
- I have tried to delete and recreate the share

What can I try?

Comment: I have deleted the share, reset the security settings, reset the owership, re-applied security settings re-created the network share.. same behaviour :-(  Could there be some corruption in the Active Directory?

Comment: Strange thing, sharing a subfolder within the offending one, will allow the blocked user to access shared folders. The problem seems to lie into the main folder (c:\Users)

Comment: More thoughts: the blocked user can access the share \\COMPUTERNAME\C$ ... this is crazy!

Comment: Effective Permissions tab?

Comment: tried that too, apparently the user has all the permissions ticked (enabled)

Comment: More news: the blocked user is also part of the "Doamin Admins" group. Assigning that group with full control permissions to the share, will succeed.
This sounds crazy because the same blocked user is in the current group with full control permissions (failing, while other users succeeding). How can it be that the same user will fail in one group and succeed in the other?